# Remove whitespace in query GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: mysql

I have query like this :

```
SELECT a.CONTAINER, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT a.COIL_NO SEPARATOR '; ') AS COIL_NO FROM tb_barang a 
   WHERE DATE(a.TGL_TRANSFER_SYSTEM)  = "2016-05-04"

GROUP BY a.CONTAINER
ORDER BY a.CONTAINER ASC
```

It gives me result like this :

```
+-------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| CONTAINER   | COIL_NO                                                                                                                                                                                        |
+-------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| MRKU7516008 | DNA07X1B530031612A            ; DNA07X1B530031631A            ; DNA07X1B530031610A            ; DNA07X1A431031620A            ; DNA07X1B530031638A            ; DNA07X1A431031612A             |
| MSKU4469584 | DNA07X1B530031636A            ; DNA07X1B530031615A            ; DNA07X1B530031614A            ; DNA07X1A431031607A            ; DNA07X1B530031635A                                             |
| PONU0415152 | DNA07X1B530031613A            ; DNA07X1A431031635A            ; DNA07X1A431031629A            ; DNA07X1B530031617A            ; DNA07X1A431031626A            ; DNA07X1A431031621A             |
| PONU0551375 | DNA07X1A431031641A            ; DNA07X1A431031613A            ; DNA07X1A431031616A            ; DNA07X1B530031629A            ; DNA07X1B530031620A            ; DNA07X1B530031639A             |
+-------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

As you can see, The field COIL_NO have a lot of whitespace character, Can I replace those whitespace in my query ?

Any help it so appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this;)

```
SELECT a.CONTAINER, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT RTRIM(a.COIL_NO) SEPARATOR '; ') AS COIL_NO FROM tb_barang a 
WHERE DATE(a.TGL_TRANSFER_SYSTEM)  = "2016-05-04"

GROUP BY a.CONTAINER
ORDER BY a.CONTAINER ASC
```

Function `RTRIM` will return the string with trailing space characters removed, take a look of [string-functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_rtrim).